# Find diversity in strings of same length

Tags: python, difference

I want to calculate the diversity in a `list` of `String`s. The number returned should be between `0-1`, where `1` would mean that the `list population` is only populated by the same string over and over.

I've tried creating two functions - one that calculates the average `ascii`-value of all `String`s, and one that calculates the diversity of one `String`, relative to all the other.

The `ascii`-values of my strings (lower case letters) are between `97` and `122`. That's why I subtract `-97` everytime I use the function `ord(letter)`. Also I'm dividing by `26` because it should be the number of possible letters that we have.

Edit: With the code below I'm getting negative numbers, and I'm not sure if the diversity is correctly calculated. Adding `abs()` might help me with the negative numbers, but I'm not sure that it's a recommended/good solution.

```
import random

def diversity(testword, population):
    testword_ascii = 0
    testword_letters = list(testword)

    for letter in testword_letters:
        testword_ascii += ord(letter)
        testword_ascii -= 97

    return (testword_ascii/len(testword) - average_ascii(population)) / 26

def average_ascii(population):
    total_ascii = 0

    for i in range(len(population)):
        newlist = list(population[i])
        for letter in newlist:
            total_ascii += ord(letter)
            total_ascii -= 97

    return total_ascii / len(population) / len(newlist)

population = []
for i in range(100):
    created_word = ""
    for i in range(5):
        letter = chr(97 + int(26 * random.random()))
        created_word += letter
    population.append(created_word)

for i in range(len(population)):
    if diversity(population[i], population) < 0.5:
        print ("The diversity of " + population[i] + "is too low! It's: " + str(diversity(population[i], population)))
```

Comment: What is the problem that you are facing?

Comment: Yep...what is actually the question here?

Comment: I just edited the post. My issue is that I'm getting negative numbers which is making me doubt how I calculate my diversity, I think there's something wrong somewhere but I can't pinpoint it.

Comment: Hmm first you don't need 'list(word)' as you can iterate over a string. Second, I do not see why it should not get negative. Third, if I get your definition right `aaaaaa` would be less diverse than `bbbbbb`. so wouldn't it be better to calculate a mean and a standard deviation for a word?

Comment: In that case the two above words are equally (non) diverse

Comment: Ok, so basically my method won't work. But am I not already calculating a mean through the "average" function?

Comment: Standard deviation might be a better choice, it's true that `aaaaa` should not be less diverse than `bbbbb`.

Comment: By the way it depends on the situation, because the diversity is always relative to the population. For example if the population has many `b`s but few `a`s, then `bbbbb` should have lower diversity than `aaaaa`.

Comment: I think you might want to consider `levinshtein distance` as a measure of string similarity

Comment: You need a definition you can compute by hand on a small data set. That gives you a) something to compute, and more importantly b) test cases. Right now I could just return a random value between 0 and 1 without looking at the inputs, and you can't prove me wrong. (Although I guess I would have to detect the 1.0 case, which you did define.)

Comment: From just the first paragraph, it looks like you just want `1-(len(set(ss))-1)/len(ss)`, although I’d call it *uniformity* rather than diversity.